# fetching date and time into excel sheet through c#

Tags: c#

I am exporting a label's text field into an excel sheet.
The problem is that when i export the date and time from the label's text field it is shown as '#' in that excel sheet.
How can I convert it into normal date time
Here is my code

```
myrange.cells[6,1]=label1.text.Tostring();
```

myrange is the object to my excel application

Please help

Comment: Have you tried converting it to a date-time in your c# code first and then insert it into Excel?

Comment: Yes. It is shown perfectly in c# application in the label

Comment: Have you tried expanding the column width? Hash signs in Excel generally mean there is more data than the current column width allows to be shown and it can't truncate it.

Comment: @pranav Moved the comment to an answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried expanding the column width? Hash signs in Excel generally mean there is more data than the current column width allows to be shown and it can't truncate it.